# Upload info that appear when share web link on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url

I have made a website. I did it with wordpress, making a custom theme.

All works fine, but I have a problem. 
When I share any url on facebook, the info is not showed correctly. Only shows correctly if I go to open graph stories and I fetch the newest info.

I must do it for any url of the website?
Is posible do it for all urls once?
Or any other option?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to check if **ALL** your OG tags are correct, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

or just simply use **Facebook OGP plugin** for Wordpress, which makes your work easy. Search WP plugins here https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=facebook+OGP